# Adding a target to UIButton in UITableViewCell with didSet

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, refactoring, didset

I am trying to refactor my code and I can't seem to active the handleFavoriteStar() action from the SearchController when the button is tapped. I was following this video by LBTA on refactoring: https://youtu.be/F3snOdQ5Qyo

Formula Cell:

```
class FormulasCell: UITableViewCell {
    var searchController: SearchController! {
            didSet {
                buttonStar.addTarget(searchController, action: #selector(searchController.handleFavoritedStar), for: .touchUpInside)
            }
        }
        var buttonStar: UIButton = {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.setImage( #imageLiteral(resourceName: "GrayStar") , for: .normal)
            button.tintColor = UIColor.greyFormula
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return button
        }()
}
```

Search Controller:

```
class SearchController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let formulaCell = FormulasCell()
        formulaCell.searchController = self
        setupTableView()
    }


     @objc func handleFavoritedStar() {
            print("Added to Favorites")
        }
}
```

Comment: What's in your `setupTableView()` method? I think what's happening is you're creating an instance of your cell, but that's not the cell that's going to appear in the table view. You need to get the instance of the cell in `func tableView(_, cellForRowAt:)` instead.

Comment: Yep that did the trick. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! FormulasCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.searchController = self
        return cell
    }
```